# Gradle clean fails because of lint & timber

Tags: android, gradle, lint, android-lint, timber-android

Using Android Studio 1.5.1 on Windows 7, and gradle 2.8 or 2.10, I got the following error when trying to run a gradle clean (only when using Timber):

```
gradle clean
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.                           
WARNING [Project: :app] To shrink resources you must also enable ProGuard         
:clean                                                                               
:app:clean FAILED          

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete file: C:\blabla\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.jakewharton.timber\timber\4.1.0\jars\lint.jar

* Try:         
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Found this:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190812
and that:
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5041014
But for Android Studio & gradle, we have no control on the compilation  (so no control over the URLClassLoader calls).

Comment: I keep getting the same error, and Unlocker to manually delete the file :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable all of Timber's lint checks, in build.gradle:

```
android {

  lintOptions {
    disable 'LogNotTimber', 'StringFormatInTimber', 'ThrowableNotAtBeginning', 'BinaryOperationInTimber', 'TimberArgCount', 'TimberArgTypes', 'TimberTagLength'
  }
}
```

I also suggest submitting a PR that fixes the issue so you can turn these checks back on. You don't want to suppress these indefinitely.

Comment: Probably also `TimberExceptionLogging`.

Answer (score 1):

Update `Timber` to 5.0.1 and probably `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to 7.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

downgrade the timber from 4.x.x to 3.1.0

Comment: Clearly that Phiter :)
And can't downgrade, need the 4.x version.

Answer (score 0):

I simply deleted `Timber.tag()` function and it was fixed

Use this

```
Timber.e("msg")
```

Instead of this

```
Timber.tag("PACKAGE").e("msg")
```